# Insert into collection after selecting data from another collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have 8 collections with data but we want to have all the data in one collection with one more extra field "Source" here we will update like 1,2,3,...,8 so that we can know which data came from which collection and also can cross verify that number of data is correctly inserted into the collection.

In MySQL what we used to do 
insert into test (rowid,title,name,createdby,source)
select rowid,title,name,createdby,1 from test_1

and it will insert the data from the table test_1 to table test with the source name 1.

Here also I want to have like this. Not getting idea in MongoDB how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from v4.2** you can use aggregation with [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) stage. E.g.

```
db.src1.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { Source:1 } },
    { $merge: { into: "result"} }
]);

db.src2.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { Source:2 } },
    { $merge: { into: "result"} }
]);

etc...
```

---

**For previous versions** you will need to map-reduce into a temporary collection, then run aggregation to shape the results:

```
db.src1.mapReduce(
  function() {this.Source = 1; emit(this._id, this)},
  function(key, values) {return values},
  {out: {merge: "tmpMerge"}}
);

db.src2.mapReduce(
  function() {this.Source = 2; emit(this._id, this)},
  function(key, values) {return values},
  {out: {merge: "tmpMerge"}}
);

... etc ...
```

When all collections are merged into tmpMerge, [replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and output to the resulting collection:

```
db.tmpMerge.aggregate([
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$value"}},
    {$out: "result"}
])
```

Comment: I was running like this db.getCollection("sample(1stWeekData)").aggregate([
    { $addFields: { Source:1 } },
    { $merge: { into: "all_data_collection"} }
]); But getting error {
 "message" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$merge'",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 40324,
 "codeName" : "Location40324",
 "name" : "MongoError"
}

Comment: Which db version? $merge is available from 4.2

Comment: I'm using the db version 4.0.0

Comment: I have added a workaround if you gonna do it once. If it is recurring process you'd better upgrade.